# Android L CardView horizontal

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, android-cardview

I have a need to display three cards in horizontal order, one after the other. The cards should fill the whole width of the screen. I wanted to use the `CardView` that was introduced with `Android L`. But I don't know how to **display the cards horizontally**. Don't know if that's even possible.
Has anyone experimented more with this CardView and can give me some advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see the problem. The `CardView` is just another View and can easily be wrapped inside a `LinearLayout`. So in your case create a LinearLayout, set the `orientation` to `horizontal`, `weightSum` to 3 and put your CardViews inside those Root-Layout and your done.

As an example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:prefix="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        prefix:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="CardView1" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        prefix:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="CardView2" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        prefix:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="CardView3" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Which would look like this:

[image: CardViews in LinearLayout]

Comment: I am sorry, I kind of though that one CardView will hold all three TextViews for example.. I don't know where I got that idea, but thank you for clearing that up. +1